# Snap not working on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: snap

I am use Ubuntu 16.04. I see on snap's home page that it installed as default on Ubuntu 16.04. But when I run any command with snap, I can't take any result includes :

> snap --version

Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt upgrade
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq snapd
sudo snap install core  
snap find vlc
```

Results of `snap --version` on Ubuntu 16.04 with an updated Linux kernel installed:

```
:~$ snap --version
snap    2.31.2
snapd   2.31.2
series  16
ubuntu  16.04
kernel  4.4.0-119-generic
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer here is you didn't have snapd installed. Run this:

```
sudo apt-get install snapd
```

then close/reopen terminal. Try snap --version again and it should now work.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of the accepted answer.

Comment: The accepted answer does not specify why this is an issue, only what to run. Just trying to help the next person out.